# input textchange action event with php

Tags: php, events

so I was wondering if there are any action event like a text changing in an input in an html page using php, like:

```
<?php
//the function to actionv_event of the input text change//
{
$accueil='href ="accueil.html"'
}
?>
```

if anyone could help me i'd apreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. But PHP runs on the server side, and only responds to requests made to the server - so it can't know about what the user does in the browser. For that you need Javascript, which has a `change` event for input elements.